# Get address of global operator delete?

Tags: c++, operators, c++20, unique-ptr

Say I want to (for some reason) explicitely pass the global deleter to a unique_ptr as second argument. I guess the compiler must have some way of figuring out its address. How would I accomplish that? The following code doesn't compile:

```
#include <memory>

class some_class { };

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<some_class, decltype(delete)/*???*/> ptr { new some_class, delete/*???*/}
}
```

And what is the notation of getting operator addresses of class operators?

Comment: Have you taken a look at [`std::default_delete`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/default_delete)?

Comment: Note that that is not `operator delete`.  `operator delete` only frees memory; it is not equivalent to a `delete` expression, which destroys objects before freeing the memory they reside in (using `operator delete`).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot take the address of a `delete` expression because it is an expression, not a function.  `delete` itself is just a language keyword.  It exists only to form delete expressions.

If you want a deleter that deletes an object using a `delete` expression, use `std::default_delete`.  Of course, that's the default deleter for `std::unique_ptr`, so there's no need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: `delete` is a keyword or an operator, not an expression. Expression would be `delete p;`

Comment: @273K Clarified a bit